# Overlaying shapefile layers in R

Tags: shapefile, r, layers, overlay, mapping

I'm very inexperienced in using R for GIS. I looked at other posts but couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to create a map that shows a municipality, roads through it and shop locations. I've installed and added packages `sf`, `raster`, `rgdal` and `ggplot2`.

I have two questions.
First, I've found two ways to load shapefiles to R:

```
munboundary<-shapefile("Filename.shp") and 
munboundary<-readOGR("Filedirectory", "Filename")
```

Are there differences between both? Both seem to work.
Once I've loaded the three shapefiles I'm trying to plot all three in one map.
I've looked up that I can us `add=TRUE` to overlay shapefiles but it doesn't work in my case.

```
plot(munboundary, col="#FFCC99")
plot(roads, add=TRUE)
plot(supermarkets, add=TRUE)
title("Supermarket access in municipality X")
```

The first one (`munboundary`) is plotted correctly but the others don't appear. There is no error message, in the console it seems to have worked but the shapefile isn't visible on the map.

I tried to find an alternative online that works and ran into this method:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = munboundary, fill="#CCFFCC") +
  geom_sf(data = roads) +
  geom_sf(data = supermarkets) +
  ggtitle("Supermarket access in municipality X")
```

but this one doesn't work either. Again looking at the console there seem to be no problems but now nothing shows up in plots.

I've just been stuck for multiple hours and feel like the ultimate noob right now.

Summary information:

```
summary(munboundary) 
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates: min max x 146.17037 146.51399 y -39.15919 -38.77096
Is projected: FALSE
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs]

summary(roads)
Object of class SpatialLinesDataFrame 
Coordinates: min max x 440884.8 454233.8 y 5668710.8 5681023.7 
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string : [+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs]
```

Comment: You should show us something about your data - `summary(roads)` and the other data would be useful. I suspect its that the data have different coordinate systems (one might be lat-long degrees, the other something else) but that's a guess (and a guess I'd put some money on) without further information.

Comment: The two ways of opening the shapefile are essentially the same except `shapefile` can only read shapefiles and `readOGR` can read lots of different spatial data formats. You should also look into using the `sf` package instead of `sp` for spatial data, there's lots of advantages and `sp` is pretty much deprecated now.

Comment: @Spacedman
Thanks for your reply! Not sure I can give all the info as it's a graded uni assignment. 'summary(munboundary) Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame Coordinates: min max x 146.17037 146.51399 y -39.15919 -38.77096 Is projected: FALSE proj4string : [+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs]' 'summary(roads) Object of class SpatialLinesDataFrame Coordinates: min max x 440884.8 454233.8 y 5668710.8 5681023.7 Is projected: TRUE proj4string : [+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs]'

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would help to need to mine the comments for critical information (and there are better formatting tools available for the question body).

Comment: I've edited. Its the coordinate system. Search for how to project or transform spatial objects coordinate systems.

Comment: Transforming with st_transform worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, many packages come with their own function to open a file. The current state of the art for working with vector data in R is the `sf` package, like @Spacedman already mentioned. To open your shapefile in `sf`, simply use:

```
munboundary<-st_read("Filename.shp")
```

As Spacedman also correctly assumed (not taking credits here), your data is not in the same projection. In this case, the roads data is probably in your desired coordinate system, whereas your municipality data is just in longitudes and latitudes. To reproject your municipality boundaries to the coordinate system of the roads, simply use:

```
munboundary <- st_transform(munboundary, crs = st_crs(roads))
```

Now try to plot again, see whether it worked.